# Two wwwroot on Azure

Tags: visual-studio, azure, wwwroot

In my VS2015 environment I have a folder structure like this:

```
--/project
----/wwwroot
-------/js
-------index.html
----web.config
----project.json
...
...
```

When I publish my app to Azure, Azure puts everything under site/wwwroot.  In this case I have two wwwroot folders, one under another.  I don't mind this but my home page is not accessible.  If I change the virtual applications/directories settings to point to site/wwwroot/wwwroot in Azure, I can see the home page but the application is not usable (WEB APIs, etc).

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: Is this a DNX application?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have both **web.config** and **Project.json**.

So is this ASP.NET core or the legacy ASP.NET application? You will see another wwwroot in case of a ASP.NET core application.

See this article once on how to publish the web app: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/publish-to-azure-webapp-using-vs.html

Comment: That was it.  I did not notice the second wwwroot at first.  Thanks.